# Install Windows 98 through PXE

Tags: linux, pxe, windows-98

I have an old Pentium machine with a broken CDROM drive and no real way to boot except for PXE.

What would be a way to install Windows 98? Would it be possible to boot into a Linux distribution and work from there?

Comment: What are you asking?  How to install Win98 or how to install Linux?

Comment: I would replace the cd drive. Then install normal way.

Comment: If I could get mostly through the installation by booting Linux and writing the Windows 98 installation files to the HDD?

Comment: I added a Windows 98 method for putting the proper installation files on the hard drive. That should work. That is how I install a VM.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can install Windows 98 via PXE (not certain however).

Get a USB CD Drive and install Windows 98 using the CD and the USB Cd Drive.

Windows 98 is very old and you normally must install it the normal way Windows 98 is installed.

I have Windows 98 running in a VM

The other way to install is to get the folder with the CAB files from the CD and on the computer where you are installing Windows 98, copy the folders in the CAB files to C:\Windows\Options\CABS   and install Windows 98 by running Setup in the CABS folder

Comment: Seems someone has done it before https://kentie.net/article/pxe98/index.htm so "cannot" seems incorrect. I'm loathe to provide a link only answer but... I suspect its probably possible

Comment: Thanks. I edited my post to provide some flexibility